# How can I use Arrow-kt's Some() in Groovy code?

Tags: groovy, kotlin, spock, arrow-kt

I'm trying to test my Kotlin code, which has Arrow-kt types, using Spock in Groovy. However, I'm not able to use Arrow-kt's additions such as `Some`. For example, I have a test as follows:

```
    @Unroll
    def "add returns #expected for queryRecord #queryRecord"() {
        given:
        def ip = "ip"
        def rule = "rule"

        when:
        def result = unit.add(ip, rule)

        then:
        1 * dynamoDBMapperMock.load(ActionRecord.class, ip) >> queryRecord

        result == expected

        where:
        queryRecord        | expected
        new ActionRecord() | None.INSTANCE
        null               | Some(new ActionInternal("ip"))
    }
```

While the first data row succeeds with no problems, the second one fails with the following error:

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: package.name.EventSpec.Some() is applicable for argument types: (package.name.ActionInternal) values: [ActionInternal(dropletIp=null)]
Possible solutions: Mock(), Spy(), Stub(), dump(), Mock(groovy.lang.Closure), Mock(java.lang.Class)`

I've tried `.some()` as well, but not to avail. Apparently Groovy can't access Kotlin extensions, but `Some` is simply a data class[[1](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/master/modules/core/arrow-core-data/src/main/kotlin/arrow/core/Option.kt)], so I'm not sure why I cannot use it in Groovy.

Comment: `new Some(...)` you're in Groovy now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Arrow [Datatypes](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/datatypes/intro/) in `Groovy`, the result is not as idiomatic as in `Kotlin` because the library heavily depends on extension functions and functions in the `companion object`

**Example**

```
import arrow.core.Option
import static arrow.core.OptionKt.getOrElse

static main(args){
    println 'What is your name?'
    def name = Option.@Companion.fromNullable(System.in.newReader().readLine())
        .filterNot { it.isEmpty() }
        .map { it.toUpperCase() }

    println("Welcome ${getOrElse(name) { 'Anonymous' }}")
}
```

**Output**

```
'Welcome JOHN' (or 'Welcome Anonymous' if the provided name is null or empty)
```

As you can see, to be able to use `getOrElse` extension function, we need to import it as a static method

**Hint**

Do not use `Some` directly unless you are absolutely sure the value is not `null`, otherwise, you should rely on `Option.fromNullable` to safely lift the value to the `Option` context (i.e create `Some` or `None` depending if the value is `null` or not)